# Perl SSH connection to execute telnet

Tags: perl, ssh, telnet, tunnel

I tried the following to access a router via a central admin server as "ssh hop" server

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -X

use strict;
use Net::OpenSSH;
use Net::Telnet;

my $lhost = "linuxserver";
my $luser = "linuxuser";
my $lpass = "linuxpassword";

my $chost = "routername";
my $cpass = "Routerpassword";

my $prompt = '/(?:Password: |[>])/m';
my @commands = ("show users\r");

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($lhost,
'user' => $luser,
'password' => $lpass,
'master_opts' => [ '-t' ],
#'async' => 1 # if enabled then password cannot be set here
);
my ($pty, $err, $pid) = $ssh->open2pty("telnet $chost");

my $t = new Net::Telnet(
-telnetmode => 0,
-fhopen => $pty,
-prompt => $prompt,
-cmd_remove_mode => 1,
-output_record_separator => "\r",
#-dump_log => "debug.log",
);

my $end = 0;

while (!$end) {
  my ($pre, $post) = $t->waitfor($prompt);
  if ($post =~ /Password: /m) {
    # send password
    $t->print("$cpass");
  }
  elsif ($post =~ /[>#]/ && @commands) {
    my $cmd = shift(@commands);
    if ($cmd !~ /[\r\n]/) {
      $t->print($cmd);
    }
    else {
      print $t->cmd($cmd);
    }
  }
  else {
    $end = 1;
    $t->cmd("exit");
  }
}
#close $pty;
$t->close();
```

Unfortunately I always get the following error:
read error: Input/output error at test.pl line 71

Can somebody help me please or is there a better solution only to test if a telnet connection via the "hop" server is possible or not?

The connection looks like:
workstation --ssh-> server --telnet-> router

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're running `telnet` on the remote ssh host and trying to connect your ssh tty to a new `Net::Telnet` session. That's not going to work. Maybe look into Expect? http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod

Comment: I only want to check if a telnet session to the router is possible from the admin server. I can only connect to the admin server via ssh and to the router via telnet. So if there is another possibility I would also use that one. But I´m really new to perl so i need a little more help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think best option is to make an SSH-tunnel to your admin server and use it for telnetting to the router.

Answer (score 2):

Getting [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aTelnet) to work over [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) sometimes is not as easy as it should be and it requires some experimentation to get to the right combination of flags and calls that make it work.

For instance, instead of telneting to the target host, use netcat to open a raw connection (or [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) support for TCP forwarding if tunnels are allowed on the proxy).

[Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect) + [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) may be a better option.